# Detect touch event on a view when dragged over from other view

Tags: android, android-view, ontouchlistener

How do I detect the touch event if the user touches on view A and drags to bottom over the view B. I want to detect the touch event in View B.

I added touch listener in view B but doesn't receive events if the user initially touched A and dragged over the B.

[image]

Comment: [SEE THIS ALSO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309111/programatically-execute-another-touch-event-when-one-touch-event-occures-in-andr)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use the code bellow to achive your request:

**Method to test view bounds** (used in code beloow)

```
    Rect outRect = new Rect();
    int[] location = new int[2];

    private boolean isViewInBounds(View view, int x, int y){
        view.getDrawingRect(outRect);
        view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        outRect.offset(location[0], location[1]);
        return outRect.contains(x, y);
    }
```

**Testing with two `TextView`**

```
    final TextView viewA = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final TextView viewB = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

**Setup viewA**

The empty `OnClickListener` is required to keep `OnTouchListener` active until `ACTION_UP`

```
    viewA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {}
    });

    viewA.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int x = (int)event.getRawX();
            int y = (int)event.getRawY();
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                if(isViewInBounds(viewB, x, y))
                    viewB.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                else if(isViewInBounds(viewA, x, y)){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onTouch ViewA");
                    //Here goes code to execute on onTouch ViewA
                }
            }
            // Further touch is not handled
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**Setup viewB**

This is only required if you also want to press on viewB and drag to viewA

```
    viewB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {}
    });

    viewB.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int x = (int)event.getRawX();
            int y = (int)event.getRawY();
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                if(isViewInBounds(viewA, x, y))
                    viewA.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                else if(isViewInBounds(viewB, x, y)){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onTouch ViewB");
                    //Here goes code to execute on onTouch ViewB
                }
            }
            // Further touch is not handled
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Regards.

Comment: how would the code look like in case of greater than 2 views?

Comment: Cool nice one. Helped me.

Comment: This code is not working for me. It shows only the last view i.e if i drag from ViewA to ViewB then it logs onTouch ViewB and if i drag from ViewB to ViewA then it logs onTouch ViewA. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: How can I just get x, y position on viewB of ACTION_MOVE triggered from viewA's touchlistener ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that you need override `ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` method in your ViewGroup that contains Views A and B. The original implementation defines the target view when the container receives `MotionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and then dispatches all the following touch events to the target view until receives `MotionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` or `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL`.

In your case the target view is A or the containter itself (depands on your container `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` method implementation). So you should override such behaviour and dispatch touch events not only to the target view, but also to all the views, that under the touched area (for example to view B).

If you are interested you can share code sample and I'll try to help you further.

Comment: [I ALSO HAVE SAME PROBLEM AT THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309111/programatically-execute-another-touch-event-when-one-touch-event-occures-in-andr). can you give some demo code for help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are returning true from the onTouchEvent of the view A then the event is not propagated. In this particular case when A is below B return false from onTouch of view A.

It would also help if you can post some code.

Answer (score 1):

In `View` *A*, Override `onTouchEvent` as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{

    float x = event.getRawX();
    float y = event.getRawY();
    if ( (B.getLeft() <= x <= B.getRight()) &&
         (B.getTop() <= y <= B.getBottom())
       )
    {
        Log.i("A", "Motion Event is currently above B");
        B.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return true;
}
```

In `View` *B*, override the same method, making sure you **return false**:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    //TODO handle touch event
    return false;//this will allow A to continue using the event
}
```

Comment: Let's let @dcanh121 test it out first. Or you could offer a constructive comment - such as why you believe it doesn't work and how you believe it should be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the drag and drop framework.

Comment: That is only avalible for 3.0 or later

Answer (score 0):

When you are over View B, call it's `onTouch` manually.

```
if (viewBRect.contains(x, y)) {
    viewBsonTouch(view, motionEvent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how can I call the circle menu creation state when user lifts his finger from view B. Below is the sample code
circleMenu = findViewById(R.id.circle_menu);

```
    circleMenu.setMainMenu(Color.parseColor("#CDCDCD"), R.color.acik_yesil, 
    R.color.kirmizi)
                .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#258CFF"), R.drawable.add)
                .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"), R.drawable.mul)
                .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#6d4c41"), R.drawable.sub)
                .addSubMenu(Color.parseColor("#FF077D8F"), R.drawable.div)
                .setOnMenuSelectedListener(new OnMenuSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMenuSelected(int index) {
                       
                        switch (index) {
                            case 0:
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "add", 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "mul", 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                case 2:
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "sub", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break; 
                case 3:
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "div", 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
```