# Android simple drag and drop?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, drag-and-drop

A friend asked me to make him a simple drag and drop poll for android.
Since I am a beginner on Android, and also with programming in general, i don't know hot to approach such a task. I tried using LayoutParams and TranslateAnimations, but that was a dead end.

Could anyone give me tips or hints(or a easy-to-use library) on how to approach this?

[image: I would like to drag and drop the items] - I will only need to drag the items vertically.

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Have a look at my answer in this post [Detect touch event on a view when dragged over from other view][1].

Regards.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980156/detect-touch-event-on-a-view-when-dragged-over-from-other-view/13505174#13505174

Answer (score 2):

There are some examples for this:

[TouchListView.java](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist/blob/master/src/com/commonsware/cwac/tlv/TouchListView.java)

[Drag-And-Drop-Android](https://github.com/mtparet/Drag-And-Drop-Android)

[TouchInterceptor.java](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/blob/master/src/com/android/music/TouchInterceptor.java)