# Detect fling for a view inside container

Tags: android

I have a view (let's say an imagebutton) centered inside a RelativeLayout. I am able to detect a fling for the imagebutton using GestureDetector only if the touch starts inside the imagebutton. How to detect a fling that starts outside the imagebutton, intercepts it and end also outside?

Thanks for help.

Comment: what if you process the gesture in the layout and see if it collides with such or such view?

Comment: Yes, it's a possible solution. Something quicker? :)

Comment: C this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980156/detect-touch-event-on-a-view-when-dragged-over-from-other-view looks like a very aimilar problen though not exactly but they describe 4 alternatives

Comment: Hmm Luis's way seems viable, I'll try it tomorrow. Thank u a lot to pointing me at it.

Comment: Worked like a charm, with some tweaks: I used the GestureDetector to check for fling in the insideView and it needs also ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP events, while it receives obviously only ACTION_MOVE from the container. So the first interacting event's action has to be dispatched as ACTION_DOWN and once the user interacts with the inner view you also has to dispatch every event until ACTION_UP regardless they are inside or outside inner view bounds. Thanks!

Comment: So... Vote me up! ^g^

Comment: Cannot vote a comment! :)
Issue a reply

Comment: Dqmn. Remember me when u reach the quote!! ^^