# Release button outside the button area

Tags: java, android, button

Pretty simple question: I have a button which changes appearance on ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP. How do I avoid ACTION_UP being triggered if they have pressed down, kept their finger on the screen and moved their finger away from the button? Currently if they press down and slide their finger away from the button, it is still DOWN. Then when they release their finger from the screen, the button is still triggered...this is not the behaviour I want.

For example if you see tinder's main like/dislike buttons - once the finger is moved away from the button (if held down on the screen) the button action is cancelled (once the finger is released).

Thanks! It is a simple but specific question which I can't seem to find the answer to anywhere. It must be possible if tinder does it I guess

Comment: I think it is definitely possible. Although I would think if you really want this functionality. Imagine that the user hits the button down, drags his finger off the button, the image will stay the same for that button. Now if the user wants to hit the button again should the button show the button_down image of the button_up?

Comment: User presses button and drags finger away from button -> as soon as the finger leaves the button area the button should go back to OFF state (button up image). That's how tinder does it anyway and it works quite well

Comment: Ok, Temporary solution, You can implement `onTouchListener()` and use `ACTION_MOVE` to identified area of View.

Comment: Have you tried using ACTION_CANCEL?

Comment: Something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980156/detect-touch-event-on-a-view-when-dragged-over-from-other-view

Answer (score 0):

If possible,  you want to set the button background (or source image for ImageButton) to a [Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector) drawable. If you do this then all the state changes will be handled for you.

To answer the question, `Views` will continue to receive touch events until the `View#onTouchEvent()` returns `false` or until an `ACTION_UP` event is called which indicates the last finger has stopped touching the screen.  So, if you don't want `ACTION_UP` to be called, then you simply return false when the event occurs that you don't want.

Comment: Unfortunately on ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP I'm starting an animation to change the appearance. SO I'm not using a selector.

Comment: The other parts will work.  Detect when the finger is out of range in ACTION_MOVE events and return false when it is.