# what is this: while ACTION_MOVE allow for a new ACTION_DOWN?

Tags: java, android, button, ontouchlistener

How do I allow for new `ACTION_DOWN` touches while I am still holding my finger on the screen after having triggered a previous `ACTION_DOWN` event?
It's probably easiest to show a gif of what I would like to achieve:

[image: a short animation showing buttons being pressed sequentially]

`G` is touched, the finger moves to `A` without releasing, and `A` gets appended to `G` above in the `textview`. The finger moves to `S`, which again is appended, and then the finger releases, triggering `ACTION_UP`.

Basically, I have a number of buttons, all of which have an `onTouch Listener`. When a button is pressed, the text-value of that button gets appended to a `textview` (just like the animation shows). 
But I can't figure out how to re-enable `onTouch ACTION_DOWN` for any button once the first one is pressed, and I am holding the finger down. *Note: I am not interested in the drawing of the line that follows the finger*

It's not that I need code; I can't even find anything on the basic logic. I have seen dozens of threads on here asking for something similar and none really help me. What is this feature called? It's not a multitouch gesture since I am only touching with one finger, one thing at a time- but in sequence without `ACTION_UP`. Some motion event? Do I work with focus? Do I need a canvas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set a touch listener on your layout's view and try to get X and Y and detect if X and Y of the touch point are on your Views.

But the post is no case of greater than 2 views. You can refer the post.

[Detect touch event on a view when dragged over from other view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980156/detect-touch-event-on-a-view-when-dragged-over-from-other-view)