# android get button text while touch down and move

Tags: java, android, button, ontouchlistener

I have a layout with 4 Buttons and text view and would make a small game by select letters to create a word.

My question is about how to get more than one button value in one single touch and move over the button? I tried by this code but get just one value every single touch and when move not get any value of other buttons

layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtresult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="102dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="A" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:text="T" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:text="C" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
        android:text="F" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activty

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {
    Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4;
    TextView txtresult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        txtresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtresult);

        btn1.setOnTouchListener(this);
        btn2.setOnTouchListener(this);
        btn3.setOnTouchListener(this);
        btn4.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.btn1:
                    txtresult.setText(txtresult.getText().toString() + btn1.getText().toString());
                    break;
                case R.id.btn2:
                    txtresult.setText(txtresult.getText().toString() + btn2.getText().toString());
                    break;
                case R.id.btn3:
                    txtresult.setText(txtresult.getText().toString() + btn3.getText().toString());
                    break;
                case R.id.btn4:
                    txtresult.setText(txtresult.getText().toString() + btn4.getText().toString());
                    break;
            }


        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Result should be like this:

[image]

Comment: What is the issue with your approach ? thats how it should be done, no ?.Give some example if possible

Comment: @KrishnaSharma issue when i touch for example "C" get letter c and when move to another letter like "A" not get any thing  i wouldto get any letter when i move ti it

Comment: Ran your code, I could get all letters in bottom result textview. I press C texresult value "C", then pressed A now texresult value "CA" and so on... Please explain your requirement with good example.

Comment: @menasoft: Did you solver the problem?

Comment: @user1090751 yes by this question answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980156/detect-touch-event-on-a-view-when-dragged-over-from-other-view

Comment: @menasoft: That code is not working for me. It shows only the last view i.e if i drag from ViewA to ViewB then it logs onTouch ViewB and if i drag from ViewB to ViewA then it logs onTouch ViewA. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: @user1090751 you can make main array and  temp array log views if you grag on viewA remove it from main array and add it to temp array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should set a touch listener on your layout's view and try to get X and Y and detect if X and Y of the touch point are on your buttons.

Take a look at [Detect touch event on a view when dragged over from other view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980156/detect-touch-event-on-a-view-when-dragged-over-from-other-view)

Answer (score 0):

this is my idea, try it

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        if(get_letter(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY() != "")
            result.append(get_letter(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
    }
}

private String get_letter(float x, float y) {
    if(is_contain(x, y, btn1)) return btn1.getText();
    else if(is_contain(x, y, btn2)) return btn2.getText();
    else if(is_contain(x, y, btn3)) return btn3.getText();
    else if(is_contain(x, y, btn4)) return btn4.getText();
    else return "";
}

private boolean is_contain(float x, float y, Button view) {
    RectF rect = new RectF();
    view.getHitRect(rect);
    return rect..contains((int)x, (int)y);
}
```